# useEffect not running when state changes

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, asyncstorage

I have a screen (MyPics.js) that shows a collection of images that the user selects from another screen. I get the selected images from asyncstorage.

All works fine if I select images and then reboot the simulator. When I navigate to the MyPics.js screen, I see all of the images stored in AsyncStorage from previous image selections.

```
  const MyPicsScreen = props => {
    const [picList, setpicList] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("I'm in!! picList data is: " +  picList);
      AsyncStorage.getItem("mypics").then((response) => {
      const currentData = JSON.parse(response);
      setpicList(currentData);
      console.log("Current picList data will be: " + currentData);
    });
   }, []);


  return (
<View style={styles.wrapper}>
  <ScrollView>
    <View style={{flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>

      {picList ? picList.map((item, index) => {
        return (
            <View key={index} style={styles.viewItem}>
              <Image style={{width: 200, height: 131}} source={Images[PicList[item][3]]} />
            </View>
          );
        }
      ) : <View><Text>You haven't selected any pics yet</Text></View>}

    </View>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
   );
 };
```

Terminal shows:

```
  I'm in!! picList data is:  //No data, as expected. Nothing is retrieved yet, then...
  Current picList data: pic001,pic007,pic099 // That shows, correctly, what's stored and screen shows those images
```

But if I add images, the new images don't show up unless I reboot the simulator. Plus, no read out in the console, so useEffect is not running to get the data and reset the state.

I'm assuming that going back to the MyPics screen causes a re-render, but I may be wrong.

I made 3 buttons on the MyPics.js screen that manually runs either removeItem or setItem or getItem on asyncstorage which then removes or sets or gets images then updates the picList state.

That works.

When I use the buttons it gets or removes previously set images or sets a new image and the screen re-renders to show the state change.

So, useEffect is not running when I navigate to the MyPics.js screen. It only runs on the first render.

When I add in the picList state as a dependency,

```
  }, [picList]);
```

it works but the console is running in an infinite loop.

Is that normal? Should I just ignore the infinitely scrolling console or am I missing a step? Should I be using a focus listener to re-render the page on a re-visit as I only need the new data when I come back to the MyPics screen.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and
>   unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This
>   tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props
>   or state, so it never needs to re-run. This isn’t handled as a special
>   case — it follows directly from how the dependencies array always
>   works.

So passing an empty array to your `useEffect` is roughly equivalent to (except `useEffect` fires *after* the initial paint) the `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` functions of class components.

Comment: Exactly. In fact, the problem with the infinite loop when you add `[picList]` comes because you're calling `setpicList(currentData)`. `currentData` is a new created object (even though the content might be the same, `picList` is not === `currentData`). So, each time the effect is triggered, it calls the setter again. That's the infinite loop

Comment: Yes, the loop doesn't happen when I set the second argument to an empty array, but then it won't update when I go back out, select new images, then go back to the MyPics screen. I need to tell it to "watch" the state and update when I re-visit the page. It seems like I have to force a re-render to make it work properly.

Comment: You might want to access the async storage from whatever component you're using to select new images then.  Or at least notify this component of image changes so it knows when to make the call

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to watch the same state you're responsible for updating, you know?

Comment: I assume that that's exactly what state is for, to change and update. My logic: Start app. Go to MyPics screen. If I have previously chosen pics, they display. If not, go to another screen that displays pics and choose some.
Chosen pics are added to asyncstorage.
Go back to MyPics page.
Page re-renders on entry, checks asyncstorage with useEffect, updates page.

Problem: useEffect does not re-check asyncstorage on re-entry to screen, which it should.
Only way to do that is to add in state as a second argument to useEffect. But that causes a loop.
Surely this is a common task.

Answer (score 2):

After a lot of pain and wasted time, this works:

```
 useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("mypics").then((response) => {
  setpicList(JSON.parse(response);
});
}, []);

const getList = useCallback(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("mypics").then((value) =>{
  setpicList(JSON.parse(value));
});
}, [picList]);
```

Some very practical examples for functional components can be found in this thread:

[React navigation didfocus event listener works differently between class component and functional component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57467317/react-navigation-didfocus-event-listener-works-differently-between-class-compone)

Focus detection is needed when coming back to the screen so that the useEffect function runs again.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Kelvin Aitken and @Danny Buonocore for support

I wondered why `useEffect` hooks only work during initial loading and failed whenever I tried to paginate more items.

I later found that I should pass any dependency/state in `[]` to tell hooks to render anytime state changes.

```js
const [fetchItemInput, SetFetchItemInput] = useState(input);

const fetchMoreItemBtn = (nextCursor) => {
    const newInput = { ...fetchItemInput };
    newInput.after = nextCursor;
    return SetFetchItemInput(newInput);
  };

  useEffect(() => {

    handleFetchItem(fetchItemInput)
      .then((res) => {
            ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
            ...
      });
    return () => {};
  }, [fetchItemInput]);       // Any changes run the effect
```

Thank you again for your support.